# Balck bar appears on top and bottom of iphone 6S

Tags: objective-c, ios9, xcode7

I have an ongoing ios project, and it is almost done. Meanwhile apple released new ios version (`ios 9`) and devices (`iphone 6S` & `iphone 6S+`).Client demanded a build for newly released 6S, and we gave a build, since the screen size of 6S is similar to 6 and we have used resizing feature for design elements, we gave it without thinking second time. But unfortunately it has some black bar in bottom and top side of the screen as client said, 6S is not even released in our country to check.And we have installed new mac and xcode version to check in simulator, but it is ok in 6S simulator.And we gave another build taken from new Xcode , same issue is there.

Client is upset and we are in trouble. Please help some one. Thanks.

> Note: It is working fine in iphone6.

Comment: maybe my question is silly, because it is actually a few years old topic by now, but have you done the proper support for screen with ratio 16:9? or do you still support handsets with the screens with ratio 2:3 only?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As of iOS9, your project must contain launch images. The 'ZOOMED' mode they had for iPhone6 devices is now deprecated and cannot be used (if your base SDK is iOS9).

Instead, applications which do not contain launch images for iPhone6 devices will be letterboxed.